# Importing Vufoira Scene into native android app

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am working on AR app made with unity + vufoira and I wanted to embed it in a native android app. I used this procedures to embed my app [Embedding Unity In Android App](https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a) . But I keep having the following error.

> 03-04 07:22:24.160 12649-13939/yenettaapp.beblocky E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer
>                                                               java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
>                                                                   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
>                                                                   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/yenettaapp.beblocky-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/yenettaapp.beblocky-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/yenettaapp.beblocky-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/
>   03-04 07:22:24.205 12649-13939/yenettaapp.beblocky E/Unity: Exception in callback: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> UnityEngine.AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer
>                                                               java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
>                                                                   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
>                                                                   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/yenettaapp.beblocky-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/ye
>   03-04 07:22:24.229 12649-14048/yenettaapp.beblocky E/mono: Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>                                                                at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                                                at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in :0 
>   03-04 07:22:24.229 12649-14048/yenettaapp.beblocky E/mono: Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>                                                                at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                                                at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in :0

How can I get around this error ?

Comment: Same issue as this I think https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/androidjavaexception-javalangclassnotfoundexception-comvuforiavuforiaunityplayervuforiainitializer-error

Comment: Its not solved yet tho .  .  .

Comment: At which step of the procedure did you get that error? While exporting from Unity or after importing into Android Studio?

Comment: After importing in unity. The application will crash just when its about to run the activity where the Unity Scene + Vuforia  are embedded in.@SawThinkarNayHtoo

Comment: I don't get it. After importing in Unity or Android Studio?

Comment: @SawThinkarNayHtoo, I meant after importing to android studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. This is how I fixed it:

- In the project build.gradle I added this under allprojects repositories:

> ```
>    flatDir {
>             dirs 'libs'
>         }
> ```

- In my module build.gradle I added the dependencies:

> ```
>   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>   implementation(name: 'VuforiaWrapper', ext:'aar'
> ```

Hope this may help you

Comment: [Please, format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: What is the different with   ' implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) ' and  ' compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) '

Comment: 'compile' has been replaced with 'implementation'. 'compile' will be removed an the end of 2018

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried that Embedding Unity In Android App tutorial from Medium and it didn't work.

Try this [Unity3d tutorial -Export Unity Project to Android Studio](https://bettercallunity.blogspot.in/2017/09/unity3d-tutorial-export-project-unity.html).

1. First in Unity Build Settings, make sure you choose Gradle for Build System, Export Project, Development Build and Script Debugging.

[image: Build Settings Unity3D]

2. Also, make sure you change the Gradle dependency version in Android Studio.

[image: Gradle Android Studio]

Here is [a similar question](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-merge-a-Unity-project-with-an-Android-project) from Quora.

Comment: Its quite different from the question you suggested. I don't think it has nothing to do with the gradle file.