# Unity Gradle build failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

i've been struggling with this issue for days now and i can't seem to find a way to solve it, here is the full error :

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity2017.2\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleDebug"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
]
stdout[

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.877 secs
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

here is my gradle.build content :

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'android.arch.core.runtime-1.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'android.arch.lifecycle.livedata-core-1.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'android.arch.lifecycle.viewmodel-1.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'cardview-v7-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.asynclayoutinflater-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.cardview-v7-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.coordinatorlayout-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.cursoradapter-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.customtabs-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.customview-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.documentfile-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.drawerlayout-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.interpolator-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.loader-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.localbroadcastmanager-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.percent-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.print-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.slidingpanelayout-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-compat-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-ui-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-utils-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-fragment-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-media-compat-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-v4-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.viewpager-28.0.0-alpha1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.github.vungle.vungle-android-sdk-5.3.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.ads.mediation.unity-2.1.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.ads.mediation.vungle-5.3.0.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-license-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-license-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-license-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-license-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-gass-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-gass-license-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-gcm-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-gcm-license-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-iid-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-iid-license-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-location-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-location-license-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-license-11.8.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.sglib.easymobile.easy-mobile-1.0.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-2.1.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'constraint-layout-1.0.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'onesignal-unity', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'percent-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'unity-ads', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':answers')
    compile project(':beta')
    compile project(':crashlytics')
    compile project(':crashlytics-wrapper')
    compile project(':fabric')
    compile project(':fabric-init')
    compile project(':GoogleMobileAdsPlugin')
    compile project(':OneSignalConfig')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 21
        applicationId 'com.chorusworldwide.upjump'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'

        }
    }

}
```

for some reason it keeps overwriting its buildToolsVersion to "'28.0.0'" even that i specifically set the build settings to this : 
[image]

I also added my own gradle.build file to Plugin/Android which is the same file but with a different BuildToolsVersion set to 27.0.0, yet, still the build.gradle file located in Temp folder inside the project is resetting itself to "28",

I also added my own gradle.build file to Plugin/Android which is the same file but with a different BuildToolsVersion set to 27.0.0, yet, still the build.gradle file located in Temp folder inside the project is resetting itself to "28", 
and finally here is some screenshots of my SDK manager :

[image]

The partially installed for Android (P) is because of this (i don't have to install them all isn't ?) : 
[image]

the SDK tools : 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:** after removing 28.0.0-rc1 from build tools, the build.gradle start building with version 27, but now am getting a new error :

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity2017.2\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleDebug"
stderr[
C:\Projects\UpJump\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius').

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\DevTools\New_SDK\build-tools\27.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
]
```

Comment: Try to remove the build tool 28.0.0-rc1 from Android SDK.

Comment: @Shaman just did, please check OP update. thanks!

Comment: Check this similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106942/importing-vufoira-scene-into-native-android-app/49125433#49125433

Comment: This was one of the steps that got me to the solution, but I needed one more:
1) In your project, go to Edit > Find > Find in Path...
2) Search for "buildToolsVersion" without the quotes.
3) Replace all instances of versions "buildToolsVersion '28" with "buildToolsVersion '27".
4) Profit.

Comment: @AWrightIV sorry for the late reply, but "find" don't do anything in unity for me, nothing shows up when i chose it, am i missing something ?

Comment: @alasipknot I'm sorry, I should have specified: I meant use Find in Android Studio. This assumes that you've already exported your project, but you can still edit the files without exporting if you search your project directory in your file system for "buildToolsVersion". You should find build.gradle files. Edit those as above. I should have split this out as an answer before, so I'll do that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it!

my main issue was here :

[image]

see all these 28.0.0-alpha files, the problem start occurring because of these, i am 100% sure of it because when i rolled back (thankfully am using version control) one of the main differences was that these libraries weren't there, i deleted them, but they kept coming back due to the "Play Service Resolver", so i figured it has nothing to do with whatever version i have installed in my Android SDK and it was 100% related to one of the plugins.

I created a new project, imported GoogleAdsMediation for Unity (that's the most important plugin) and did the "Resolving" thing, and there was no "28" files at all, so it wasn't google plugin, i kept doing with this with all the plugins we have. 
import -> delete all libraries -> force resolve.
Until i found the culpable one, it was OneSignal, their dependencies configuration (or something) forced the resolver to import these "28.0.0-alpha" libraries, i deleted that version of OneSignal, imported an older one (from an older version of our project) and Boom! problem solved :)

I hope this helps.

cheers!

Comment: I also had this issue. I found this link <https://forum.unity.com/threads/2017-3-new-gradle-error.522427/> which suggested removing all the build tools down to 26.

Comment: as much as it was a blunt decision, I deleted my plugins folder, and the android resolver downloaded only what it needed. fixed the problem for good!

(I started having this problem after updating both the google ad and play services assets)

Answer (score 5):

[AWrightIV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521245/5183414) got me most of the way there. But the solution for me was less complicated. I generated a mainTemplate.gradle file that unity creates when you turn on "use custom gradle file" in the player settings and changed the buildToolsVersion line.

Original line in Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle:

> `buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'`

New:

> `buildToolsVersion '27'`

Answer (score 2):

The answer in the similar issue mentioned by @SawThinkarNayHtoo will get you most of the way. Here's that link again: [Importing Vufoira Scene into native android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106942/importing-vufoira-scene-into-native-android-app/49125433#49125433)

The gist of it is you want to export your Unity project while targeting Android. There are great tutorials elsewhere about how to do this, but here's the link from the answer above:
[Export Unity Project to Android Studio](https://bettercallunity.blogspot.in/2017/09/unity3d-tutorial-export-project-unity.html)

After following the steps above, I needed one more step:

1. In Android Studio, open your exported project and go to Edit > Find > Find in Path...
2. Search for "buildToolsVersion" without the quotes.
3. Replace all instances of versions "buildToolsVersion '28" with "buildToolsVersion '27".

If necessary, you can also edit the files without exporting. Search your project directory in the file system for "buildToolsVersion". You should find build.gradle files. Edit those as above.

Comment: thank you, it's been a ~week since i posted this, and i no longer have the "28" version forced on,  i just did what you said, and all of my buildToolsVersion (i have 4 in total) are 27.0.1, the compileSdkVersion is 27, and the dependencies is gradle:3.0.1, and i still get similar errors when i build, should i change 27.0.1 to 27.0.0 ? thanks

Comment: my doubt is in the dependencies here : https://pastebin.com/SwmbXNy4 i am a total noob when it comes to native Android development, can you please check if there is any duplication or "un-mixed" versions ? because now when i build from Android studio i get this error : https://pastebin.com/803GkrLy knowing that multiDexEnabled is set to true. thanks again!

Comment: this is a weird one https://i.imgur.com/aTPS8qh.png despite that my project doesn't refers at all to v28, am still getting android.support v28 (the 1st 3 jars in the last link)

Comment: also a bunch of them here : https://i.imgur.com/ak8M2Wm.png am really confused now lol

Comment: alright, so, apperantly the usage of 28alpha has nothing to do with what my SDK manager contains, its caused by the "Play Services Resolver" inside Unity, whenever a Resolve happens, it downloads a bunch of new libraries, including these 28alpha ones : https://i.imgur.com/dqtl9pX.png

Comment: @alaslipknot I'm not familiar with that plugin, but I hope you found the solution to your build issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was ok until I downloaded the latest 29 sdk build tools. I deleted the build tools from my sdks and it solved my problem